# Why am I unable to select the following values from the dynamic drop down list?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver  
import time  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get('https://devbusiness.tunai.io/login')
time.sleep(2)
driver.maximize_window()

# Create variables for login credentials.
username = "your username"
password = "your password"

username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "loginUsername");
username.send_keys("kevin@tunai");

password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "loginPassword");
password.send_keys("xxxxx");

login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='app']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/button");
login.submit();
time.sleep(2)

# Wait for login process to complete. 
WebDriverWait(driver=driver, timeout=10).until(
    lambda x: x.execute_script("return document.readyState === 'complete'")
)
# Verify that the login was successful.
error_message = "Incorrect username or password."
# Retrieve any errors found. 
errors = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "flash-error")

# When errors are found, the login will fail. 
if any(error_message in e.text for e in errors): 
    print("[!] Login failed")
else:
    print("[+] Login successful")

driver.get("https://devbusiness.tunai.io/dashboard/salon_menu_service")

service = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='page-content']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/button")
service.click();
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"input").send_keys("Hair Dying")

price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='page-content']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/input")
price.clear()
price.send_keys("50")

baseprice = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='page-content']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/input")
baseprice.clear()
baseprice.send_keys("10")

category = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='page-content']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]")
Select.select_by_visible_text("Category 2 - BeautyPOS")
time.sleep(3)
```

I wish to select one of the values from the drop down list but it didn't work when i using "select" function.I couldn't figure it out what's the issues. Been tried many ways to debug it but failed...Appreciate if anyone could help,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide your whole code and the site you want to scrape?

Comment: The reason why this don't work is because `Select only works on <select> elements`. Try changing the class name `multiselect__option` to `multiselect__option--selected` of span in path `div.multiselect__content-wrapper ul.multiselect___content li.multiselect__element span` in the html of dynamic select.

Comment: class="multiselect__option--selected".
Is that what u mean? It doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of ideas, I dont know vue.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to select in the salon service menu? The xpaths that you've given do not locate any element on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way how to select category in your styled list.

```py
from selenium import webdriver  
import time  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get('https://devbusiness.tunai.io/login')
time.sleep(2)
driver.maximize_window()

# Create variables for login credentials.

username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "loginUsername");
username.send_keys("kevin@tunai");

password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "loginPassword");
password.send_keys("123456");

login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='app']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/button");
login.submit();
time.sleep(2)

# Wait for login process to complete. 
WebDriverWait(driver=driver, timeout=10).until(
    lambda x: x.execute_script("return document.readyState === 'complete'")
)
# Verify that the login was successful.
error_message = "Incorrect username or password."
# Retrieve any errors found. 
errors = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "flash-error")

# When errors are found, the login will fail. 
if any(error_message in e.text for e in errors): 
    print("[!] Login failed")
else:
    print("[+] Login successful")

driver.get("https://devbusiness.tunai.io/dashboard/salon_menu_service")

service = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='page-content']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/button")
service.click();
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"input").send_keys("Hair Dying")

price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='page-content']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/input")
price.clear()
price.send_keys("50")

baseprice = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='page-content']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/input")
baseprice.clear()
baseprice.send_keys("10")

# Category button
category_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='page-content']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]")
# An "Category 2 - BeautyPOS" item in list of categories
category_select = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"""//*[@id="page-content"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/ul/li[2]/span""")

# Click category button to show list.
category_button.click()
# Click on category you want select.
category_select.click()

time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Appreciated bro! It works now!